# QtMainWindow initialized event

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I need to start a job when [`QMainWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html) and all its widgets are initialized and rendered.

How can I catch such event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this.

Sophisticated:

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::showEvent(e);
    static bool firstStart = true;
    if (firstStart)
    {
        emit startJob();
        firstStart = false;
    }
}
```

And easy one (suitable only, if you show main window right after creating):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ...
    QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(job()));
}
```

**Update**:

Like `Chris` said, `showEvent` is much more appropriate here, than `paintEvent`.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for correcting. Sophisticated indeed ^_^ That's why I prefer simple solutions.

Comment: There's no guarantee of the easy one succeeding, simply creating a `MainWindow` and not showing it would cause `job()` to run with an initial paint occurring.

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate to use showEvent() instead of paintEvent()